# Getting an error in my Chirp Python App, think I may have overwritten my .chirprc file

Tags: chirp

I'm receiving an error where Chirp is having trouble identifying the sound board on my Raspberry Pi 3 when using the Python setup instructions. I suspect the issue is related to a user error on my part. When performing the step I copied my credentials from my Applications page and pasted them into a text file which I saved as .chirprc (overwriting rather than pasting into the file)

Here is an example (minus the specific values) of what my .chirprc file looks like:

[default]
app_key = xXxXXxxxXXXxxXXXxXxXXxXxx
app_secret = xxXxXXXxXxxXXXxXXXXxXxXxxxXxxxXXxXxXxxxXXxXxXXxXxX
app_config = XxXXXXxXxXxxxXxxxXXxXxXxxxXXxXxXXxXxXxxXxXXXxXxxXXXxXXXXxXxXxxxXxxxXXxXxXxxxXXxXxXXxXxX

I suspect in hindsight that there are other values that probably already existed in the file and is why your instructions say "...and paste into your ~/.chirprc file"

I'm thinking I can probably delete the directory, uninstall with pip3 and then re-install with pip3 to get the file back (I tried deleting the file I created and running pip3 again but that didn't populate the missing file).

Any chance you can point me perhaps to where the .chirprc file may be sitting in the SDK or online in a github repo so I can do a copy and paste and then re-insert my credentials? Or perhaps paste the default .chirprc file online as a response.

Once I get this I think everything else should work properly on my Raspberry Pi 3

Answer (score 0):

This file must be created manually by the user, it is not created by the SDK.

You simply need to copy the contents from the Python block at https://developers.chirp.io/applications into a .chirprc file in your user directory.

Try out the example at https://github.com/chirp/chirp-python-examples/tree/master/demo and copy and paste any console messages here.

You will need to ensure that the same configuration is used in your .chirprc and the testing device.